# Understanding MeshLambertMaterial Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have this code, it works perfectly:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/texture01.jpg' ) } ) );
mesh.scale.x = -1;
scene.add( mesh );
```

But when the material change to MeshLambertMaterial, the object is not displayed and no shows errors.

I need it for this type of material to play with the opacity ..

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using lights?

Comment: Too many hours without sleep .. Thank you!